# how to show query while using query annotations with MongoRepository with spring data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, mongorepository

I'm using MongoRepository in spring boot to access mongo:

```
public interface MongoReadRepository extends MongoRepository<User, String> {
    @Query(value = "{$where: 'this.name == ?0'}", count = true)
    public Long countName(String name);
}
```

and it could work, but i wonder know the exactly query it accessing mongo

how to do that?

i try to adding some config at properties like below:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query=DEBUG
```

and don't work.

could somebody help?

Answer (score 97):

**I add the line (below) in application.properties and works fine:**

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG
```

**for query:**

```
@Query("{$and: [{'$or' : [{ 'name': {$regex : ?0, $options: 'i'}}, {'description': {$regex : ?1, $options: 'i'}}]}, { 'deleted' : ?2 }]}")
```

**obtain this log:**

```
2016-09-27 10:53:26.245 DEBUG 13604 --- [nio-9090-exec-3] o.s.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate      : find using query: { "$and" : [ { "$or" : [ { "name" : { "$regex" : "c" , "$options" : "i"}} , { "description" : { "$regex" : "c" , "$options" : "i"}}]} , { "deleted" : false}]} fields: null for class: class com.habber.domain.Entity in collection: entities
```

Comment: make sure you have imported log4j

Comment: I even imported log4j and tried the same solution, but its not working for me

Comment: remove the .MongoTemplate.  It works as logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core

Comment: @VishalA check [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76723193/8913704), you may need to adjust your main logger configuration.

Answer (score 37):

Also, you can use a `yml` config file, put it in your `application.yml` file.

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate: DEBUG
```

Answer (score 27):

For ReactiveMongo add this property to your .properties file

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate=DEBUG
```

Comment: you saved my life, thanks mate

Answer (score 9):

> This is a late answer but I found the correct answer hasn't been given yet based on the question.

The answer already given by the people may be valid for other scenarios. But, if you are using the `MongoRepository` then the correct configuration would be the following:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.query= debug
```

You are using the `Query` in your configuration instead of `query` which is wrong.

When  you add correct configuration then the logger would be like:

```
25-06-2020 17:58:43.301 [http-nio-9001-exec-10] DEBUG o.s.d.m.r.query.MongoQueryCreator.complete(162) - Created query Query: { "customer.id" : 2}, Fields: {}, Sort: {}
```

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution is valid. But if you use `@DocumentReference` you may notice that N+1 queries won't appear in log.

If you want to know if referenced collection was queried, add the following property:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoDatabaseFactoryReferenceLoader=TRACE
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the complete solution is according @Wilder Valera and @Chaojun Zhong

When you want to log for MongoTemplate the answer:

```
logging:
   level:
       org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate: DEBUG
```

When you want to log for ReactiveMongoTemplate you should use:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.ReactiveMongoTemplate=DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind, that even if you do

```
logging:
  level:
    org:
      springframework:
        data:
          mongodb:
            core:
              MongoTemplate: DEBUG
```

you still may not be able to see the DEBUG statements if your main logger's configuration set to output only INFO messages. In our case, we had a `logback.xml` where we had an appender for frameworks with `level: INFO`. Until we changed this one as well to DEBUG we didn't see the queries from MongoDB:

```
<appender name="FRAMEWORKS" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>
        ...
</appender>
```