# How can I log actual queries to MongoDB with mongo java driver in Micronaut application

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver, mongo-java, micronaut-data

I am setting the mongo logger as below

```
<logger name="org.mongodb" level="debug"/>
```

When I run the query using java driver in Micronuat application

```
DEBUG org.mongodb.driver.protocol.command - Sending command '{"aggregate": "product.category", "pipeline": [{"$match": {"$and": [{"_id": {"$oid": "60c4aed3afb396342bf90802"}}, {"subCategory._id": {"$oid": "60cc5dd52b5cf415ded7de5d"}}]}}, {"$group": {"_id": 1, "n": {"$sum": 1}}}], "cursor": {}, "$db": "FeteBird-Product", "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "9UGXhsvnSZ+FXRCDwsiyWA==", "subType": "04"}}}}'
```

But if I copy this command and try to run in mongoshell it won't work, how can I show what exact query it is generating. So that I can run that query and see the output on console

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48326299/how-can-i-log-actual-queries-to-mongodb-with-mongo-java-driver

Comment: What you are seeing is a full representation of the query, the first part with the aggregate and the pipeline is the query the rest is just additional info about the db where you executed the query, check the mongodb-shell sintax but all the information is there

Comment: How can I execute that command

Answer (score 0):

Try running your command using `runCommand`

```
mongo shell> use database_name
mongo shell> db.runCommand({"aggregate": "product.category", "pipeline": [{"$match": {"$and": [{"_id": {"$oid": "60c4aed3afb396342bf90802"}}, {"subCategory._id": {"$oid": "60cc5dd52b5cf415ded7de5d"}}]}}, {"$group": {"_id": 1, "n": {"$sum": 1}}}], "cursor": {}, "$db": "FeteBird-Product", "lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "9UGXhsvnSZ+FXRCDwsiyWA==", "subType": "04"}}}})
```

Comment: Any idea a how can I convert 60c4aed3afb396342bf90802 to BSON, getting an exception while running the above command

Comment: com.mongodb.MongoCommandException: Command failed with error 14 (TypeMismatch): 'BSON field 'OperationSessionInfo.lsid.id' is the wrong type 'object', expected type 'binData'' on server localhost:27017. The full response is {"ok": 0.0, "errmsg": "BSON field 'OperationSessionInfo.lsid.id' is the wrong type 'object', expected type 'binData'", "code": 14, "codeName": "TypeMismatch"}

Comment: Actually error says to fix `OperationSessionInfo.lsid.id` field, not `subCategory._id` field. `$oid` is a way to build `ObjectId` instance

Comment: db.runCommand(
{"aggregate": "product.category",
 "pipeline": [
 {"$match": {"$and": [{"_id": "60c4aed3afb396342bf90802"},
  {"subCategory._id": "60cc5dd52b5cf415ded7de5d"}]}
 }
 ], "cursor": {}, "$db": "FeteBird-Product"}
) this works but lots of modification

Comment: You can try replacing `"lsid": {"id": {"$binary": {"base64": "9UGXhsvnSZ+FXRCDwsiyWA==", "subType": "04"}}}` with `"lsid: {"id": BinData(4, "9UGXhsvnSZ+FXRCDwsiyWA==")}`

Comment: unknown operator: $oid on running the command

Comment: What version of monogdb are you using? Try to replace every `{"$oid": "something"}` with `ObjectId("something")`

Comment: MongoDB shell version v4.2.0. I did getting unknown operator: $oid on running the command

Comment: For mongo shell mode try using mongo shell representation of strict commands from https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/mongodb-extended-json-v1/