# Is there any feature in mongo like as hibernate.showSql to track the query execution in mongodb

Tags: spring-boot

I need to track the query execution in console using spring boot with mongodb is there any feature like as hibernate.showSql in mongodb

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to show query while using query annotations with MongoRepository with spring data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37118047/how-to-show-query-while-using-query-annotations-with-mongorepository-with-spring)

Answer (score 0):

Add following line in app.properties file to enable logging.

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG
```