# Is there N + 1 problem with @DocumentReference(lazy = true) Spring data mongo

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have such models

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document 
public class Parent {
    @Id
    String id;
    String name;
    @DocumentReference(lazy = true)
    List<Child> children;
}

@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Document
public class Child {
    @Id
    String id;
    String name;
}
```

and I have just the usual MongoRepository for both of them. Also I enabled logging

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate=DEBUG
```

If I select only Parents using `List<Parent> parents = parentRepo.findAll()` I make only one request to the database and I see it in the logs:

```
find using query: {} fields: Document{{}} for class: class com.test.Parent in collection: parent
```

I am looking at it via debug and I see that the children's collection is proxy and it contains only ids. It is reasonable. But what if I decide to iterate by children?

```
public void test() {
    List<Parent> parents = parentRepo.findAll();

    parents.get(0).getChildren().forEach(child -> System.out.println(child));
}
```

I still see only one request to the database in the logs, but there was more than one. How many were there?
Is there n + 1 problem?
How can I see all requests to the database including loading data using @DocumentReference(lazy = true)

Answer (score 1):

I've also faced the problem that queries to referenced tables don't appear in log.

I've found that there is another class in Spring Data MongoDB responsible for handling requests to referenced tables.

Wrote about this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75208971/6226118).

To enable enable logging when referenced collection was queried, add the following property:

```
logging.level.org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MongoDatabaseFactoryReferenceLoader=TRACE
```